# Search for text value in sql table and display it in listbox on textbox.textChanged event

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

So basically i have sql table named "Table1" which has columns -nvar(10) Name , float Value and nvar(50) Date, so 3 columns - "Name" "Value" "Date".
I have textbox1 and listbox1.
So basically i want to display table data in listbox1 which matches with texbox1 value.So textbox1 is the search area and the result is displayed in the listbox.
I want to make boolean function which returns true if value of textbox1 matches with any row in the table column and call this function for every row in every columns.

Something like that (loop through table columns and table rows)

```
   protected void Box3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string txt = Box3.Text.ToString();
           foreach (clmn in Tablename.columns){
               foreach(row in Tablename.Rows){

               if(GetSearchResults(txt))
               {
                ListBox1.add(txt);
               }
               }
           }

        }
```

and for GetSearchResults something like that

```
  public Boolean GetSearchResults(string text) {

            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
            connection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FatherDB"].ConnectionString;
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT *FROM Table1 WHERE Name Like '%@text%' OR Value Like '%@text%'", connection);
            SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);

            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@text", text);
            /code here..
            return true;

        }
```

I was also thinking about filling invisible Listbox2 with all the table data and then searching in Listbox2 instead of SQL search

Comment: What RDBMS, MySQL or SQL-Server?

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: Skip the searching , i want to display all the table data into listbox

Comment: I'll give you a general idea. work on this and let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the general idea...

```
ListBox lb = new ListBox();
string connectionString = "your connection string here";
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    con.Open();
    string query = "SELECT Name + ' ' + cast(Date as varchar(20))+' '+ cast(Value as varchar(20)) as 'Text' FROM MyTable";
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
    {
        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read()) {
                lb.Items.Add(new ListItem((string)reader["Text"]));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok so this gives me all rows from "column" what if i want to give me all rows from all columns

Comment: It gives you only `column` for all rows from `myitemstable`. If you need more columns you have 2 choices. Concatenate all columns in SQL `"Select column1+' ' +Column2 from..."` and no changes in C#. Or `"SELECT column1, column2 from.."` and add a reader for each column in c# `(string)reader["column1"]; (string)reader["column2"];`

Comment: @Arch_interpreter What do you want to display in listbox?

Comment: ok so i do `"SELECT column1, column2 from.."` and then   

` ListBox2.Items.Add(
                                new ListItem((string)reader["Name"]) 
                                + ""+new ListItem((string)reader["Value"]) 
                                + ""+new ListItem((string)reader["Date"])
                            );`
But "Value" column is float how to convert it to string

Comment: i want to display all the table content in the listbox ,so  each row is in new line

Comment: @Arch_interpreter Do this: `"SELECT Name + ' ' + cast(Date as varchar(20)+' '+ cast(Value as varchar(20) from.."` now, from the point of view of c# all strings in only one column.

Comment: @Arch_interpreter see my edition to answer. This would work for you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57344/discussion-between-arch-interpreter-and-horaciux).